# Reference Error: variable is not defined within "onclick"

Tags: angular, typescript

I am creating multiple buttons, each connected to a unique modal element. I'd like to do this with their id. I'm having trouble referencing the variable from the typescript file.

I do not have access to the implementation of function, however I do know it works; when passed a hard-coded "0", there are no thrown errors, and each button opens up the first modal.
Index is being passed to the child correctly.
I've tried interpolation, but that results in a error for security reasons.
I've tried (click) instead of onclick, but that plays poorly with the function on that line.

parent.html

```
<ul class="example" *ngFor="let v of vs, let i = index">
   <child-component
       [index]="i">
   </child-component>
</ul>
```

child.html

```
<button
    type="submit"
    id="button{{index}}" //interpolation works here
    class="updatebtn"
    onclick="function(this, index)"> //problem line
</button>
<div id="{{index}}" class="special-modal">item {{index}}</div>
```

child.ts

```
export class childComponent implements OnInit {
    @Input() index: string;
}
```

Currently getting ReferenceError: index is not defined at HTMLButtonElement.onclick.

Comment: Begin by correcting `<child-component>[index]="i"` to `<child-component [index]="i">`

Comment: You're going against angular by using the `onclick` function. This causes issues. Use `(click)="yourFunction()"` instead

Comment: How is onclick against angular? "function" here is in place for "base.modal.show". When I use (click), I get the error base is undefined.

Comment: It's outside of the angular context so it pisses angular off. Basically, angular has no idea about anything that happens in `onlick` event. If you don't use `(click)` you'll lose data binding and all kinds of other stuff that the angular change tracking keeps track of. Huge no-no

Comment: Is this inside of a form? Why is your `button`'s `type` attribute set as `submit`? I am also failing to see why value `index` is giving you. Also, passing `this` in your html is completely unnecessary. If you're button is inside an `*ngFor`, just pass in the current object into your function. Angular already knows exactly where you're at.

Comment: "function" here is in place for "base.modal.show". When I use (click), I get the error "base" is undefined. Which seems odd as it works in a limited fashion with onclick and hard coded arguments

Comment: I am not sure the button's type is relevant. "this" is necessary. I'm not granted access to that function's implementation, but I do know what arguments are needed.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know how your code is even compiling let-alone saying "Index is being passed to the child correctly". First of all, there's no @input() decorator, it'll be @Input(). Then you also need to write `<child-component [index]="i">`